# How to make Swift Codable types more versatile

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I currently am working with an API that deals with bus predictions. There is an interesting quirk with the JSON that is returned for the predictions of a certain stop. When there are multiple predictions for a stop, the JSON looks something like this:

```
...
"direction": {
            "prediction": [
                {
                    "affectedByLayover": "true",
                    "block": "241",
                    "dirTag": "loop",
                    "epochTime": "1571785998536",
                    "isDeparture": "false",
                    "minutes": "20",
                    "seconds": "1208",
                    "tripTag": "121",
                    "vehicle": "1698"
                },
                {
                    "affectedByLayover": "true",
                    "block": "241",
                    "dirTag": "loop",
                    "epochTime": "1571787798536",
                    "isDeparture": "false",
                    "minutes": "50",
                    "seconds": "3008",
                    "tripTag": "122",
                    "vehicle": "1698"
                },
                {
                    "affectedByLayover": "true",
                    "block": "241",
                    "dirTag": "loop",
                    "epochTime": "1571789598536",
                    "isDeparture": "false",
                    "minutes": "80",
                    "seconds": "4808",
                    "tripTag": "123",
                    "vehicle": "1698"
                }
            ],
            "title": "Loop"
        }
...
```

However, when there is only one prediction for a stop, the JSON looks like this instead:

```
...
"direction": {
            "prediction": 
                {
                    "affectedByLayover": "true",
                    "block": "241",
                    "dirTag": "loop",
                    "epochTime": "1571785998536",
                    "isDeparture": "false",
                    "minutes": "20",
                    "seconds": "1208",
                    "tripTag": "121",
                    "vehicle": "1698"
                }
            "title": "Loop"
        }
...
```

Notice that the "prediction" is no longer inside an array -- this is where I believe things are getting complicated when using a Swift Codable type to decode the JSON. My model looks like this for the "direction" and "prediction"

```
struct BTDirection: Codable {
    let title: String!
    let stopTitle: String!
    let prediction: [BTPrediction]!
}

struct BTPrediction: Codable {
    let minutes: String!
    let vehicle: String!
}
```

Basically what is happening is `prediction` in `BTDirection` is looking for an Array of BTPrediction, however in the 2nd case above, this wouldn't be an Array so the decoding fails. How can I make my models more flexible to accommodate both an array or a single object? Ideally, in the 2nd case `prediction` would still be an array of a single `BTDirection`. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
struct BTDirection:Codable {

    let title,stopTitle: String
    let prediction: [BTPrediction]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        stopTitle = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .stopTitle)
        do {
            let res = try container.decode([BTPrediction].self, forKey: .prediction)
            prediction = res
        }
        catch { 
              let res = try container.decode(BTPrediction.self, forKey: .prediction)
              prediction = [res] 
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Sh_Khan's answer, if you have multiple places in your API responses where this sort of thing happens, you can extract this custom decoding and encoding out to a custom wrapper type so you don't have to repeat it everywhere, like:

```swift
/// Wrapper type that can be encoded/decoded to/from either
/// an array of `Element`s or a single `Element`.
struct ArrayOrSingleItem<Element> {
    private var elements: [Element]
}

extension ArrayOrSingleItem: Decodable where Element: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        do {
            // First try decoding the single value as an array of `Element`s.
            elements = try container.decode([Element].self)
        } catch {
            // If decoding as an array of `Element`s didn't work, try decoding
            // the single value as a single `Element`, and store it in an array.
            elements = try [container.decode(Element.self)]
        }
    }
}

extension ArrayOrSingleItem: Encodable where Element: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        if elements.count == 1, let element = elements.first {
            // If the wrapped array of `Element`s has exactly one `Element` 
            // in it, encode this as just that one `Element`.
            try container.encode(element)
        } else {
            // Otherwise, encode the wrapped array just as it is - an array
            // of `Element`s.
            try container.encode(elements)
        }
    }
}

// This lets you treat an `ArrayOrSingleItem` like a collection of elements.
// If you need the elements as type `Array<Element>`, just instantiate a new
// `Array` from your `ArrayOrSingleItem` like:
//     let directions: ArrayOrSingleItem<BTDirection> = ...
//     let array: [BTDirection] = Array(directions)
extension ArrayOrSingleItem: MutableCollection {
    subscript(position: Int) -> Element {
        get { elements[position] }
        set { elements[position] = newValue }
    }

    var startIndex: Int { elements.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { elements.endIndex }

    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        elements.index(after: i)
    }
}

// This lets you instantiate an `ArrayOrSingleItem` from an `Array` literal.
extension ArrayOrSingleItem: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...) {
        self.elements = elements
    }
}
```

Then you can just declare your `prediction` (and any other property that has the potential to be either an array or a single item in your API response) like this:

```swift
struct BTDirection: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let stopTitle: String?
    let prediction: ArrayOrSingleItem<BTPrediction>?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both @TylerTheCompiler & @Sh_Khan provide very good technical input into solution that provide the mechanics of a solution, but the provided code will hit some implementation issues with the given json data:

1. there are errors in the JSON posted that will stop codable working with it - I suspect these are just copy & paste errors, but if not you will have issues moving forwards.
2. Because of the initial `direction` key the JSON effectively has 3 (or at least 2.5!) layers of nesting.  This will either need to be flattened in `init(from:)` or, as in the below, need a temporary struct for ease of mapping.  Flattening in the initialiser would be more elegant, a temporary struct is far quicker :-)
3. CodingKeys, while obvious, isn't defined in the previous answers, so will cause errors compiling the init(from:)
4. there's no `stopTitle` field in the JSON, so that will error on decoding unless it is treated as an optional.  Here I've treated it as a concrete `String` and handled it in the decoding; you could just make it a `String?` and then the decoder would cope with it being absent.

Using "corrected" JSON (added opening braces, missing commas, etc) the following code will import both scenarios.  I've not implemented the `arrayOrSingleItem` as all credit for that belongs with @TylerTheCompiler, but you could easily drop it in.

```
struct Direction: Decodable {
   let direction: BTDirection
}

struct BTDirection: Decodable {
   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case title
      case stopTitle
      case prediction
   }
   let prediction: [BTPrediction]
   let title: String
   let stopTitle: String

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      do {
         prediction = try container.decode([BTPrediction].self, forKey: .prediction)
      } catch {
         let singlePrediction = try container.decode(BTPrediction.self, forKey: .prediction)
         prediction = [singlePrediction]
      }
      title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
      stopTitle = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .stopTitle) ?? "unnamed stop"
   }
}

struct BTPrediction: Decodable {
   let minutes: String
   let vehicle: String
}
```

and then to actually decode the JSON decode the top-level Direction type

```
let data = json.data(using: .utf8)
if let data = data {
   do {
      let bus = try decoder.decode(Direction.self, from: data)
      // extract the BTDirection type from the temporary Direction type
      // and do something with the decoded data
   }catch {
      //handle error
   }
}
```

In case you're not aware, [JSON Validator](https://jsonformatter.org) is very useful for validating/correcting json.