# Generic property for Custom Object and Array of Custom Object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am getting response from the API in two different format

1.Data as an Object

```
{
   code: 0,
   message: “string”,
   data : {
       …
   }
}
```

2.Data as an Array of Object

```
{
   code: 0,
   message: “string”,
   data : [{
       … 
   }, 
   {
       …
   }]
}
```

I am currently using two models to get the parsed JSON and it is working fine.

```
public class BaseModel : Decodable {
    var code:Int?
    var message:String?
}

public class DataObject<T> : BaseModel {
    var data : T?
} 

public class DataArray<T> : BaseModel {
    var data : [T] = []
}
```

Is there any way to have a single generic property which can hold a custom object or an array of custom objects?

**Update** Based on the suggestions, I have asked the API team to update the response.

Comment: You can use an enum with associated values for the property. But also, why not just always model the property as an array (of one item, if it's not an array)

Comment: It seems like poor API design for an API to sometimes return a single object & sometimes return an array. It should always return the same thing. If there's only one object, it should return an array with one object. I'd recommend trying to make that change if possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513344/how-to-make-swift-codable-types-more-versatile

Answer (score 0):

You can implement **`init(from:)`** in the **`Codable`** model and use custom parsing to get this working.

```
public class BaseModel: Decodable {
    var code: Int
    var message:String
    var data: [DataObject]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code, message, data
    }
    
    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        code = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .code)
        message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
        if let dataValue = try? container.decode(DataObject.self, forKey: .data) {
            data = [dataValue]
        } else {
            data = try container.decode([DataObject].self, forKey: .data)
        }
    }
}

public class DataObject: Decodable {
    ....
}
```